# More complex e-mail merge & knowledge base

Tags: email, knowledge-base, merge

TLDR: Looking for a smart clipboard tool to paste text selected through a tree structure from a source database organized in said tree structure.

I am writing a lot of e-mails in which I repurpose a lot of the same responses or "bits" and just having multiple tabs open (with the "source e-mails) and copy+pasting gets tiring.

I am looking to create a structured knowledgebase that would contain all the "source texts" from which I could then more easily paste to the e-mails I am writing.

I am in inside sales so you can imagine the use case:

1 Initial cold e-mail template for: a) people who are familiar with our business b) people to whom we need to explain what we do c) people who just want to know how we differ from XYZ

2 -> Response asking about a) feature A b) feature B c) pricing d) us as a company

3 Answering those

4 -> ...

I can see the whole funnel in my mind and can imagine a tool that would "envelop" it, would contain all the artifacts (texts) possibly needed in each stage of the conversation: something based on the customer journey. But what I am really looking for is something simpler:

- a place to hierarchically store all the texts (in a tree structure)
- a way to possibly incorporate this structure into a "paste" function in my g-mail so that I can just select the text and paste it

I think tech support folks must be using something similar.

Does this make sense? : ] Is there a name / category for a tool like this?

Tech requirements:

- Should run on MacOs / be a part of one of the more popular browsers (Chrome, Safari, Brave)
- Priced < $5 / month

Appreciate your help!